# Naming Convention for a dedicated ordering column

Tags: sql, data-modeling

I have two entities: Course and Lesson. Course have many Lessons. Lesson list is to be ordered. I'm storing Course and Lesson entities into a relational database.

I want to have a column to order lessons. Later I'll `SELECT` Lessons and `ORDER BY` this column. Is there a naming convention how I should call this column?

Comment: `Order` perhaps?

Comment: Appending "Order" to the end of the column name I guess is fairly common. E.g. "LessonOrder" in your case. Or just "Order". But there's no particular rule no, you can do as you please. P.s. This question is opinion based and will likely be closed.

Comment: I'd usually avoid `Order`, of itself, because it's a reserved keyword in SQL.

Comment: SQL is quite old technology and there are plenty convention over there. I believe saving lists in database is quite common problem and there should be a common convention around this.
In the system I've started working right now they inconsistently use names like: weight, order, number, order_id.

Comment: The main thing is to establish your own naming convention that makes sense to you (either individually or your development team depending on your circumstances) and then stick to it. What everyone else does outside that is less important. And the convention itself isn't that important either so long as it's clear, and most importantly consistent

Answer (score 1):

Like @Magnus suggested, adding an order column for the lessons would be appropriate. Create a lesson table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE lesson (
    lesson_id int, 
    course_id int,
    lesson_title varchar2(50),
    lesson_descr varchar2(255),
    lesson_order int
);
```

Then you can use the following query to pull the lessons or a particular course in order:

```
SELECT lesson_title FROM lesson
WHERE course_id = '12345'
ORDER BY lesson_order ASC;
```

Comment: The implementation you provided is exactly what I've described. The question though is about naming convention.

Comment: HI @DmitryKaigorodov, if you are looking for naming convention, the most appropriate and descriptive would be to append an "_order" suffix to the column you intend to sort by.